# Python Selenium: getting rid of Firefox first run screen

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, pytest, splinter

Currently my py.test + splinter + pytest-splinter tests load a Firefox welcome screen when browser instance is created:

[image]

How one can get rid of this and have `about:blank` as a starting page as this screen is wasting some time and bandwidth on each test run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional` property to `''`:

```py
In [1]: from selenium import webdriver

In [2]: profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

In [3]: profile.set_preference('startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional', '')

In [4]: browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```